# Changing font color

Tags: text

[image]

Here is what I want to do: I have the background picture and I want to paint the text in the colors which are negative to this picture, just like the highlighted part. Is there any way it can be done so?

Comment: Please either tag the question with the software you are using, or list the software within the question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [I need an adjustment layer which will invert in the same way as when you select some text in a text layer](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/74530/i-need-an-adjustment-layer-which-will-invert-in-the-same-way-as-when-you-select)

Answer (score 1):

As long as you are using software that supports layers with the option to use different blending modes, this should be an easy effect to create.

Create white text on a layer above the background, and set the text layer's blending mode to "Difference."

---

For example, here is a text layer and background layer:

[image: Text layer]
[image: Background]

Using the Normal blending mode:

[image: Normal blending]

Using the Difference blending mode:

[image: Difference blending]