# Text selection effect replication

Tags: adobe-photoshop, photoshop-effects

I would like to ask you, if you know how can I replicate text selection overlay effect.

I tried to Invert colours, and also adding another shape and selecting blending mode Difference. Here is an example of what i'm trying to achieve:

[image]

The rectangle at the top has blending mode and the text beneath is just highlighted text - the effect I would like to achieve.

Comment: How do your own efforts fail?

Comment: @usr2564301 as you can see on the link that I've provided, there is significant difference between my effort and desired effect.

Comment: Welcome to the site! I think you will get the answers you want if you provide a little more information. For example -- you refer to blending modes; do you need to use blending modes for a reason? Otherwise, have you had a problem just creating white type and a colored rectangle behind it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your object must be *white* and the blend mode must be set to *Difference*:

[image: White layer with difference blend mode.]

Comment: that looks nice. Sorry, but I'm quite beginner. Would you be so kind and explain how did you add that color fill layer?

Comment: You can read about adjustment and fill layers in the [manual](https://helpx.adobe.com/photoshop/using/adjustment-fill-layers.html). It doesn't have to be a "Color Fill Layer" though. Anything white will do! So just make a box like the one you already did, but make it white instead.

Comment: Actually its not difference, its a inverse that has a discontinuity at 50% of intensity. In this case its same as difference but not with all backgrounds see [this near duplicate](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/74530/i-need-an-adjustment-layer-which-will-invert-in-the-same-way-as-when-you-select/). So its not allways really trivial

Comment: @joojaa, that is geeky! And cool. But it might be overkill in this case?

Comment: Yes but just so people know that its not necessarily so simple

Comment: ok, so I have placed a white rectangle, with blending set to difference on top of the gradient, and this is what i've got: https://imgur.com/a/EOUn6 @Wolff

Comment: Must be because you have a CMYK document. My solution only works in RGB. (And the text selection is an RGB effect by nature)

Comment: you are right! When I've tried it with RGB it worked perfectly. thanks! :)