# How can I manually create amp-files for curves adjustment layers in Photoshop?

Tags: adobe-photoshop

Is there a way to manually create an amp file which I can then load in Photoshop via the curves adjustment layer? Like typing the values in an hex editor or something and then create an amp file out of it...

edit: after some more research i found a post here on stack exchange that actually refers to this process of manually creating such a file. see the post by the user @joojaa here:

[I need an adjustment layer which will invert in the same way as when you select some text in a text layer](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/74530/i-need-an-adjustment-layer-which-will-invert-in-the-same-way-as-when-you-select/74533)

but still i have no clue how to actually do it ...?

Comment: Aren't curve adjustment layers saved as .ACV?

Comment: @WELZ yes when you are in point mode an acv file is saved, but when you are in pencil mode an arbitrary map or amp file is saved. since i want to manually create such a file by numbers i thought it would be better to "take" a amp file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. To make starting easy, open a existing amp file  file in a hex editor like say [online hex editor](https://www.onlinehexeditor.com/). You can begin with a file that is just a straight line.
2. Then edit the file. It is just a simple map that repeats itself 3 times. Each byte is one value. So the default no transformation is simply:

   ```
   00 01 02 03 ... FD FE FF
   00 01 02 03 ... FD FE FF
   00 01 02 03 ... FD FE FF
   ```

   where each value represents the new value for the positional value. The first position represents the black red channel and the second represent red 01 value etc.

Of course you may want to use some code to do this. It's pretty trivial to do this in say python.